# oozie distcp job execution

Tags: oozie, distcp

I have a oozie work-flow which is performing a distcp operation.
Workflow file is as below :

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.3" name="distcp-wf">
<start to="distcp-node"/>
<action name="distcp-node">
    <distcp xmlns="uri:oozie:distcp-action:0.1">
        <job-tracker>${jobtracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${namenode}</name-node>
        <prepare>
            <delete path="${namenode}/tmp/mohit/"/>
        </prepare>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                <value>${queue_name}</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
        <arg>-m 1</arg>
        <arg>${number_of_mapper}</arg>
        <arg>-skipcrccheck</arg>
        <arg>${namenode}/tmp/mohit/data.txt</arg>
        </distcp>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="fail"/>
</action>
<kill name="fail">
    <message>DistCP failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
<end name="end"/>
```

I want to set the number of mapper using -m using distcp.
How can i do that I have tried with

```
<arg>-m 1</arg>
```

and

```
<arg>1<arg>
```

But did not worked for me.
The error that I am getting is as below :

```
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.DistcpMain], main() threw exception, Returned value from distcp is non-zero (-1)
      java.lang.RuntimeException: Returned value from distcp is non-zero (-1)
```

Comment: Did you try something like `<arg>-m</arg> <arg>1</arg>`?

Comment: Yes I tried that also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Args are for input/output as described in the [documentation](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.0/DG_DistCpActionExtension.html)

> The first arg indicates the input and the second arg indicates the output

For changing the number of producers/reducers use the `configuration`  for example :

```
 <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.reduce.tasks</name>
                <value>${firstJobReducers}</value>
            </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: firstJobReducers value will be numeric and need to set in properties file, Am i right ?

Comment: @MohitRane you can set it inside the wf action - like you did in your example or use property file for the entire wf